# There was no channel that could accept the message with action

Tags: wcf, web-services

When I access my webservice *via* WcfTestClient, it returns me a few hundred results in a few seconds, so my webservice works fine.

Now, when I try to access it *via* my application, it throws me all kinds of errors.
My webservice is on a website hosted with Visual Studio, I access it on localhost, and when I navigate to the endpoint it shows me no error (just the message on how to generate a proxy class).
I already have another webservice+app, which work fine thanks to the kind gentlemen there : [WCF webservice - can't use it in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231917/wcf-webservice-cant-use-it-in-production) . Obviously I copy-pasted the config files, but no luck.
The proxy class is auto-generated by Visual Studio, *via* "Add Webservice Reference".

I have exactly the symptoms described there : http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009/04/which-binding-to-use-wshttpbinding-or.html but this site does not suggest concrete solutions, so it's not of much help to me.

The IPushMail service interface (in a DLL) :

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IPushMail

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetEmails")> _
    Function GetEmails() As List(Of CMS.Mail.MailSerialiserPushMail)

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="IncrementerNumero")> _
    Function Incrementer() As Boolean

End Interface
```

The PushMail webservice class (in the App_Code folder of the site) :

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class PushMail
    Implements IPushMail

    Public Function GetEmails() As List(Of CMS.Mail.MailSerialiserPushMail) Implements IPushMail.GetEmails
        Dim mails As New List(Of CMS.Mail.MailSerialiserPushMail)
        ' get mails
        Return mails
    End Function

    Public Function Incrementer() As Boolean Implements IPushMail.Incrementer
        ' update record
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

The PushMail app :

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text

Module PushMail

    Sub Main()
        Dim pmClient As New PushMailService.PushMailClient()
        Dim mails As List(Of PushMailService.MailSerialiserPushMail) = pmClient.GetEmails()
        For Each m In mails
            ' do stuff
        Next
        If (pmClient.Incrementer()) Then
            Console.WriteLine("FINI")
        End If
        pmClient.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Web.Config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <!-- here are a few other behaviors -->
            <behavior name="PushMailBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true" />
                </serviceCredentials>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <!-- here are a few other services -->
        <service behaviorConfiguration="PushMailBehavior" name="PushMail">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IPushMail" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityBinding">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                    <userPrincipalName value=".\NetworkService" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

App.Config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPushMail" closeTimeout="20:00:00"
                openTimeout="20:00:00" receiveTimeout="20:00:00" sendTimeout="20:00:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
                    maxArrayLength="200000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:60308/WebServices/PushMail.svc"
            behaviorConfiguration="PushMailBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPushMail" contract="PushMailService.IPushMail"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IPushMail">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value=".\NetworkService" />
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="PushMailBehavior">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And here are the errors I get :

The app throws a generic message : "An unsecured error or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner fault exception for the fault code and detail". The InnerException is not of much more help : "The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action xxx is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings".

The trace log is a bit more detailed. It starts by giving me two similar warnings, both saying "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted".

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131076</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType>
<Level>4</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-04T10:05:57.8896060Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{7d9b9578-467c-4949-ad5e-380d4ae6a0b0}" />
<Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer" ProcessID="17264" ThreadID="4" />
<Channel />
<Computer>PC-THOMAS-WIN7</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Traitement d’une exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>cf2e76e7-10-129701451365074680</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Le domaine spécifié n’existe pas ou n’a pas pu être contacté</Message>
<StackTrace>
à System.ServiceModel.UpnEndpointIdentity.GetUpnFromDownlevelName(String downlevelName)
à System.ServiceModel.UpnEndpointIdentity.GetUpnFromWindowsIdentity(WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Le domaine spécifié n’existe pas ou n’a pas pu être contacté
   à System.ServiceModel.UpnEndpointIdentity.GetUpnFromDownlevelName(String downlevelName)
   à System.ServiceModel.UpnEndpointIdentity.GetUpnFromWindowsIdentity(WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>54B</NativeErrorCode>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

A bit further down the line, it shows an error : "There was no channel that could accept the message with action xxx".

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-04T10:05:57.9286099Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{22dc2d84-586b-4221-aae4-d529e4b7560a}" />
<Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer" ProcessID="17264" ThreadID="4" />
<Channel />
<Computer>PC-THOMAS-WIN7</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Génération d’une exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>cf2e76e7-10-129701451365074680</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Aucun canal ne pouvait accepter le message avec l’action « http://tempuri.org/IPushMail/GetEmails ».</Message>
<StackTrace>
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.ThrowAndCatch(Exception e, Message message)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.ProcessItem(TInnerItem item)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.HandleReceiveResult(IAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.OnReceiveCompleteStatic(IAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel.HelpReceiveRequestAsyncResult.OnReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(TDisposable item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, ItemDequeuedCallback dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, ItemDequeuedCallback callback)
à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
à System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
à System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
à System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Aucun canal ne pouvait accepter le message avec l’action « http://tempuri.org/IPushMail/GetEmails ».</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

It looks like the domain (localhost) cannot be contacted, but I can access it with WcfTestClient ! I really don't get it...

Thanks for your help...

Comment: One thing i would like to clarify is that your service element does not have a fully qualified name and the endpoint does not have a fully qualified contract name. Make sure that these are correct on the server side.

Comment: What elements are you talking about exactly ? How can I fully qualify the names ?

Comment: <service behaviorConfiguration="PushMailBehavior" name="PushMail"> in the above line it should have the name as "PushMailService.PushMail" if i am not wrong. <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IPushMail" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityBinding">  and contract value should be "PushMailService.IPushMail". I could get your namespace from the generated app.config

Comment: The webservice does not have a namespace, apparently.

Comment: Do you mean that PushMail and IPushMail are not in any namespace. Can you post the skeleton of PushMail class.

Comment: I have added the code in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution... There was `establishSecurityContext="true"` in the web.config, and `establishSecurityContext="false"` in the app.config. I set it to true in the app.config, and now it works...