# Service works from wcfTestClient but fails in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a service. The service is working fine when I tested using wcfTestClient. When I am calling from console app client it is throwing following error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ICalculationService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Service Trace:

> Description: Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.
>   Source:System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager/28072850

What all could be the possible issues?

Reference: [There was no channel that could accept the message with action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725353/there-was-no-channel-that-could-accept-the-message-with-action)

---

**Service Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CalculationServiceInterface"
        closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
        sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="CalculationService.CalculationService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="CalculationService" behaviorConfiguration=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CalculationServiceInterface"
        contract="ICalculationService" />
  </service>
  </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client Config**

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CalculationServiceInterface"
                closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="524288" maxStringContentLength="524288" maxArrayLength="524288"
                    maxBytesPerRead="524288" maxNameTableCharCount="524288" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2724/CalculationService.svc/CalculationService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CalculationServiceInterface"
            contract="ICalculationService" name="CalculationServicePort" />
    </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

**WSDL**

```
  <definitions xmlns:import0="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:messages:v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:import1="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:data:v1" xmlns:tns="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:calculation:v1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" name="CalculationService" targetNamespace="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:calculation:v1" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />

  <types>
  <xsd:schema>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="C:\toolbox\LijosServiceApp\NewService\RestaurantMessages.xsd" namespace="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:messages:v1" />
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="C:\toolbox\LijosServiceApp\NewService\RestaurantData.xsd" namespace="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:data:v1" />
  </xsd:schema>
  </types>

  <message name="getMultiplied">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
  <part name="parameters" element="import0:getMultiplied" />
  </message>

  <message name="getMultipliedResponse">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
  <part name="parameters" element="import0:getMultipliedResponse" />
  </message>

  <portType name="CalculationServiceInterface">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />

  <operation name="getMultiplied">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
  <input message="tns:getMultiplied" />
  <output message="tns:getMultipliedResponse" />
  </operation>

  </portType>

  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_CalculationServiceInterface" type="tns:CalculationServiceInterface">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <operation name="getMultiplied">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:lijo:demos:multiplyservice:calculation:v1:getMultiplied" style="document" />
  <input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </output>
  </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="CalculationServicePort">
  <port name="CalculationServicePort" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_CalculationServiceInterface">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost/CalculationService" />
  </port>
  </service>
  </definitions>
```

XSD File:

The required XSD can be found in [One WCF service – two clients; One client does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420314/one-wcf-service-two-clients-one-client-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me admit that it was a blunder from my side. I was keeping the client configurations in output.config file (generated by the WCSF Blue tool). When I copied it to the app.config it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, Lijo. Did my answer help at all? Also, you should mark something as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely within your client config.

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:2724/CalculationService.svc/CalculationService"
```

Have you configured your local IIS to host the service at port **2724**?

Double-check this first.

**EDIT:** If you're testing with Visual Studio, [see this article](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/tip-use-specific-port-when-hosting-wcf-service-in-cassini-web-server/) for advice on configuring a specific port number.

Comment: I am testing with Visual Studio 2010; not installed on IIS.